# Pass multiple values to an argument

Tags: powershell

I would like to pass string to variable `$FileExtension`, if I pass a single value such as `$FileExtension = "*.txt"` then it working fine, but if *multiple* values such as `$FileExtension = "*.txt,*.log"` then it failed.

How to solve this problem ?

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -Include $FileExtension | Select-String -pattern "$SearchString" | group path | 
select name | Out-File $OutputLocation'\'$OutputFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Include` parameter takes a `string[]` so you can simple create an array of strings like this:

```
$FileExtension = "*.txt","*.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution of @MartinBrandl is better for performance because its directly into get-childitem command. But with this solution you must have "*" in path file of get-childitem command. Note you can use -file option into get-childitem to better performance.

An other solution is use a where command for filter extension like this:

```
$fileextension=".ini",".jpg"
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file | where Extension -in $fileextension
```

You can use -lisrt into select-string command and then you can remove group command like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "*.*" -file -Include $fileextension | 
    Select-String -pattern "$SearchString" -List | 
        select Path  | 
            Out-File $OutputLocation'\'$OutputFile
```

Comment: if i would like to search sub directory, how can i apply in your code ?